# Animated .gif distorted in Outlook 2019

Tags: html-email, outlook-2019

I have an animated .gif that is 1200px wide in total, but I'd like to scale it down to 600px wide for a clearer image in 120dpi. Below is the code that's in the message; it's displaying in the right width but the wrong height (as you can see there's no height defined, and it's not auto-scaling the way I'd like it to).

Outlook 2019 is the only email client in which it's displaying wrong. It looks fine in all other email clients. Also, the other images (.jpgs) in my message are displaying exactly the way I want them to, and they contain the same inline CSS.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<td style="padding: 0; text-align: center"><a href="https://www.lookoptic.com/collections/screen-products" target="_blank"> <img alt="FRAMES FOR THE FAMILY | Make protecting your eyes from harmful blue light a family choice. With matching frames for adults and kids, we keep it easy for the whole family to keep their eyes healthy even while spending more time in front of screens than ever." border="0" src="https://d3k81ch9hvuctc.cloudfront.net/company/HQd5zH/images/57fbdbba-e232-441f-abc2-098444d1525f.gif" width="600" style="display: block; border: 0px; outline: none;
width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 600px;background: #fff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555;" /></a> </td>

</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Screenshots would be good, or the gif itself. And a bit more code--is this in a table or div or what? Is there embedded CSS too (`<style>...</style>`)? How are you scaling it down just for 120dpi? Where is the code for that? 

In the mean-time you could try not specifying height at all (not even 'auto'). Note that Outlook desktop does not regard max-width, so you may need Outlook-specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook will ignore the style sheet for your image. So you can use the `height` and `width` tags to direct the behavior of Outlook and allow modern email clients to operate the way they need.

If your animated image on Outlook is supposed to be 600px x 600px, do this:

```
<img src="#" width="600" height="600">
```

Then for the other clients, add in an inline `style` sheet (like you did in your example.

```
<img src="#" style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 600px;" width="600" height="600">
```

This will work for any image format supported in Outlook.

Good luck.

Comment: Only width works for me on `img` tag as well. Without height the image still resizes proportionally. One reason I use height is i dont have to worry about image skewing if I change the image with a higher one.

Comment: @Syfer I would agree. If you leave the `height` blank, it turns out to be more useful in older versions of Outlook. I just wanted to show the way to control Outlook image sizes and allow modern clients to do what they need.